# Web Forwarding Frame - Change the meta / title

Tags: javascript, html, frame

I'm using 123 reg's forwarding frame for a website.

However this forwarding frame is not picking up the inner html's meta data. So the frame is loading in a non responsive format.

Has anyone come across this problem and found a fix?

I ideally need to add the following meta to the parent frame :

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Can this be done?

Thanking You!

Comment: `123 reg's forwrading frame` ? what....?! what is a forwarding frame

Comment: @vsync — It's where you rent a domain name but instead of point the DNS to your server, you point it to the registrar's site, then they create a site for you consisting of a single page containing a frame pointing to your own site.

Comment: @Quentin - why would anyone do that?

Comment: @vsync — To avoid learning how to use DNS and how to configure a web server to do virtual name hosting. (Or to avoid moving to decent hosting which allows that sort of thing to be configured).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Has anyone come across this problem and found a fix?

There isn't one.

Frame based web forwarding is, frankly, awful. This is one of the many drawbacks.

The solution is to not use it. Use real DNS that points to your actual server instead.

Comment: I totally agree with this answer. Thank You. Tight clients making this the case, unfortunatley!